# UIButton added in code not responding to touch

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm just adding a quick intro screen with a button, which compiles and displays properly, but my button doesn't respond.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSLog(@"viewDidLoad!");
   [self showIntro];
}

//  make a quick Intro screen
- (void) showIntro {
   UIImageView *myBackImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
   [myBackImage setImage:(UIImage *) [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBkgnd.png"]];

   UIButton *clickBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
   [clickBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton_pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [clickBtn setImage:(UIImage *) [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   clickBtn.frame = CGRectMake(111, 200, 75, 60);
   [myBackImage addSubview:clickBtn];
   [self.view addSubview:myBackImage];
}

- (void)myButton_pressed:(UIButton*)button {
   NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
}
```

What am I overlooking?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to use initWithFrame constructor for UIButton instead of buttonWithType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have added `UIButton` in `UIImageView` but didn't you forgot `imageView's`  `userInteraction` by `default NO`. So :

```
myBackImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**EDIT** : Just formatted